# Does the STL have a way to apply a function before calling less than?

Tags: c++

A lot of algorithms accept a comparison object. Often, I end up with something like

```
std::sort(begin, end, [&](auto const& lhs, auto const& rhs) {
    return Function(lhs) < Function(rhs);
});
```

Is there anything in the STL to apply a Function before calling less than? So I could write:

```
std::sort(begin, end, std::DoesThisExist(Function));
```

I know I could write my own, but I wonder if this already exists. I glanced through cpprefence but didn't see it. Could easily have missed it.

Comment: I don't think this exists, however, it should be very easy to write.

Comment: std::bind, see details below

Answer (score 2):

The Ranges TS (which has been merged for C++20) defines variations of many of the standard algorithms that include [**projections**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/algorithm/sort) with exactly this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you could use std::bind, but it is very verbose:

```
   typedef std::remove_reference<decltype(*begin)>::type T;
   std::sort(begin, end, std::bind(std::less<T>(),
      std::bind(Function,std::placeholders::_1),
      std::bind(Function,std::placeholders::_2)));
```